# Redux reducer failing to remove array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm having problems trying to get my reducer to work correctly in Redux. I'm new to Redux so I might be missing something simple, but I've played with it for a while and can't figure out what's going wrong.

Here is my process:

### Define argument:

First I define the index value that I need. When logged, this returns the correct number...

```
const thisCommentIndex = parseInt(comments.indexOf(comment))
```

### Function Call:

```
<div onClick={this.props.removeComment.bind(null, thisCommentIndex)}></div>
```

### Action:

```
export function removeComment(index) {
   return {
      type: 'REMOVE_COMMENT',
      index
   }
}
```

### Reducer:

```
function comments(state = [], action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'REMOVE_COMMENT' :
         console.log('removing comment with index of ' + action.index)
         return [
            ...state.slice(0, action.index), // why isn't this working???
            ...state.slice(action.index)
         ]
      default :
         return state
   }
   return state;
}
```

---

When I `console.log('removing COMMENT with index of ' + action.index)`, it logs the action.index correctly, the integer I would expect. But the function doesn't remove the element as expected.

**Strangely, if I simply pass the array index instead, it works fine (removes the array element).** (I would just do this, but due to the way I have set up my app it won't work in this case).

Am I missing something here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try surrounding `state.slice` with brackets to be sure it doesn't do decomposition first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `+1`...

```
return [
  ...state.slice(0, action.index),
  ...state.slice(action.index + 1) // <--- need to actually skip what you want to remove
]
```

Comment: Oh man. How did I miss that. I actually had it working before, but obviously changed that part without realising... Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

@Jack is correct.  Another option would be to use `Array.filter` instead:

```
return state.filter( (item, index) => index !== action.index)
```

You might be interested in the new [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs.  In particular, the page on [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) has some related examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove multiple items, then you could work through your array backwards

```
 for (var i = this.props.items.length -1; i >= 0; --i) {
   if(this.props.items[i]["selected"]) {
     this.props.deleteSelectedItem(i);
   }
 }
```