# React/Redux: state called twice? (concat(), not push())

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having an issue with adding new `todo` to `todos`, classic one. Doing it on React/Redux.

Here's `reducer-todos.js`:

```
export default function (state=[
    {
        id: 0,
        todo: "Study English"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        todo: "Run sprint"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        todo: "Call Bob"
    }], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TODO":
            return state.push({id: state.length, todo: action.todo});
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Here's the issue I get:

[image]

Somehow `todos` object becomes `4`, not Array[4]. Why is this happening?

Please let me know if additional info needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Somehow todos object becomes 4, not Array[4]. Why is this happening?

You're using `push` which will return its new size. Use `concat` instead which will return a new array with your new item added without mutating.

So this:

```
return state.push({id: state.length, todo: action.todo});
```

Should become:

```
return state.concat({id: state.length, todo: action.todo});
```

Comment: @SamKirklandWA You're welcome! Click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it so other people know your issue is solved.

Comment: Will do, let 3 minutes pass. )

Comment: Hi @Jack, sorry to bother you, but when I try to remove an element from JSON object, splice() also runs twice and deletes almost everything. Is there an alternative to it as well?

Comment: @SamKirklandWA Don't use `splice` use `slice`. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294652/redux-reducer-failing-to-remove-array-element/40294750#40294750

Comment: Thanks Jack for your help!